# I'm learning about shebangs. How do I make it work with node.js in a Mac terminal?

Tags: node.js, unix, shebang

I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("It works!");
```

I learned that env finds the node program and interprets it with node. I checked that `env` exists in /usr/bin.

When I call `node itworks.js` it works and outputs `It works!`. However, from what I understand, I should just be able to call `itworks.js` without `node` due to the shebang. But when I make this command it says `-bash: itworks.js: command not found`.

Could someone help me get the shebang to work?

Comment: Make sure the execute bit is set on the file and call with `./itworks.js` from within the directory where the file is

Comment: FYI, shebangs are **not** related to bash at all. The OS itself honors the shebang, not the shell, so a shebang works even when you're executing a program through a mechanism that doesn't have any shell -- or any terminal -- involved. (And, in consequence, this question shouldn't be tagged either `bash` or `terminal`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to make the file executable:

```
chmod +x itworks.js
```

Then you need to call it by specifying the path as well. Either:

```
/where/it/is/on/disk/itworks.js
```

or:

```
./itworks.js
```

Comment: Thanks...I will accept this answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for :

```
-bash: itworks.js: command not found
```

is because bash looks for programs in directories in the `PATH` environment variable when you do not say where the file is - it does not look in the current directory unless you tell it.

You could update the `PATH` variable with the current directory shortcut `.`, but that can be a security risk, so most run the program like this:

```
./itworks.js
```

Of course if you put your scripts all in one directory then you could add that to `PATH` in one of your start-up files.  For example, if you had a directory called `bin` in your home directory that held your scripts:

```
PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/bin"
```

You also need to add the execute permissions to the script:

```
chmod u+x itworks.js
```

The `u` indicates that we only give permission for the current user to execute this file.  If we omit the `u` then anyone can run it.